# UITextFeld Comparison Failing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitextfield

I have a UITextField and I create it like so:

```
firstnameField1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85+320*4, 80, 150, 30)];
    [firstnameField1 setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [firstnameField1 setPlaceholder:@"Firstname"];
    [firstnameField1 setDelegate:self];
    [firstnameField1 setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyNext];
    [scrollViewController addSubview:firstnameField1];
```

When the user taps the return key I want to check if the text field has anything typed into it, if its empty, the user hasn't typed anything, I want to return and show a label telling the user that field is required to be filled before they can continue, just like you see all over the place.

I do the following to check:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //Check if the user has typed anything
    if (textField.text == @"") {
        //If not, show 'required' labels
        [firstNameRequiredLbl1 setAlpha:1];
        [surnameRequiredLbl1 setAlpha:1];
        [firstNameRequiredLbl2 setAlpha:1];
        [surnameRequiredLbl2 setAlpha:1];
        return YES;
    }

    //Do all my other stuff, cut out for ease of reading, 100% doesn't affect this anyway

    return YES;
}
```

I have set a breakpoint on that last method and it jumps right past that if statement whether I type into that textfield or not.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to change **`textField.text == @""`**

to: **`textField.text.length == 0`** or **`textField.text isEqualToString:@""`**

What the **`==`** operator is actually doing in this case is checking if the strings are stored in the same area of memory rather than whether or not they contain the same characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare `NSString` text strings that way. Use this instead:

```
if ([textField.text isEqualToString: @""])
```